# Using Python decorators to gather information on available method and store that data in the class or instance

Tags: python, python-decorators

I found a lot of questions regarding decorators and classes, and access to the class instance that is being decorated. As far as I could understand, the decorator generator can not access the object instance because, at that time, no object was yet created.

Nevertheless, it seems that if a decorator uses a class reference (I mean, receives cls), then I am able to access to some class field:

```
     class Foo:
          _tags = {}
      
          @classmethod
          def _tag(cls, tag_name):
              def decorator(func):
                  def tmp(*args, **kwargs):
                      return func(*args, **kwargs)
     
                  cls._tags[tag_name] = func.__name__
                  return tmp
     
              return decorator
```

This works as a charm for subclasses, where I can write:

```
 @Foo._tag("something")
 def somethingelse():
     pass
```

But this stores the information in the father class (as expected), as we are talking about class variables.

I wonder if there is a way to have a similar behavior, but guaranteeing that each subclass has its own instance of the `_tags` property.

I can foresee some workarounds, like parsing the source code, or inspecting the functions, during `__init__`. But I was looking for a simpler way, if there is such a way.

**Edit 1:** to make it clearer, I want to decorate methods from the subclass. Thus, this is not a possibility:

```
     Class Bar (Foo):
        @Bar._tag("method")
        def method(self):
           pass
```

as the processor/compiler did not complete the creation of the class yet. Otherwise, the solution proposed of a two level dictionary with class/method would work good enough for me.

**WORKAROUND**

My decorator:

```
    @classmethod
    def TAG(cls, name):
        def decorator(func):
            def tmp(*args, **kwargs):
                return func(*args, **kwargs)

            tmp._has_alias = name
            return tmp
        return decorator
```

During `__init__`, I get this info, and store:

```
        self._tags = {getattr(self, name).has_alias: name for name in dir(self) if callable(getattr(self, name)) and hasattr(getattr(self, name), "_has_alias")}
```

Comment: `return decorator` is not indented enough. Aside from that typo(?), I don't seen any compelling reason for `Foo` to be a class. You're effectively just "renaming" a global variable `tags` to `Foo._tags`.

Comment: @chepner, thanks I fixed the indentation. Was my mistake when copying/pasting. I mean that I want to be able to subclass Foo, and to have each subclass to manage its own copy of that variable. I know that is not possible directly (its a class variable!). But I am looking for solutions to circumvent that.

Comment: Define `Foo.__init_subclass__` to add a new attribute to each subclass rather than declaring the attribute directly in `Foo`.

Comment: @chepner didn't know about `__init_subclass__`, but as it seems I am only able to call the decorator using the parent class `@Foo._tag...` and not the child class (as it is not yet defined, as described above), it complains on the field not existing. (not sure if I managed to explain properly).

Comment: I do not think that it is possible to do what I want. I was inspecting the function python passes to the decorator, and it is sent as a standard function and not as a method. Therefore, I can't tie it to a class at that point. So, probably I need to go for a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround could be to treat `_tags` as a dictionary of dictionaries, with the top level key being the name of the subclass, and its associated dictionary containing the callables wrapped by its inherited version of `_tag`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
class Foo:
  _tags = defaultdict(dict)
  @classmethod
  def _tag(cls, tag_name):
    def decorator(func):
      def tmp(*args, **kwargs):
         return func(*args, **kwargs)
      cls._tags[cls.__name__][tag_name] = func.__name__ #storing tag_name under the name of the subclass
      return tmp
    return decorator
```

Now, when creating subclasses and wrapping functions, `_tags` will store the values under the subclass name by which `_tag` was called:

```
class A(Foo):
  pass

class B(Foo):
  pass

@A._tag('test_a')
def a():
  pass

@B._tag('test_b')
def b():
  pass

print(dict(Foo._tags))
```

Output:

```
{'A': {'test_a': 'a'}, 'B': {'test_b': 'b'}}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I need to tag methods inside that class. Thus, I can't use @A._tag inside itself.